# Getting different result looping with "while", Please explain why?

Tags: php

Beginner here,
Kindly explain me the reason for the different answer.

```
$string = "If you’re looking for a way";

$pos = 0;

while (($pos = strpos($string,"o",$pos))!== false) {
echo $pos."<br/>";
$pos++;
 }
```

[Result for the above code] Output are:

```
4
13
14
21


$pos = 0;

$string = "If you’re looking for a way";
while ((strpos($string,"o",$pos))!== false) {
echo strpos($string,"o",$pos)."<br/>";
$pos++;

  }
```

[Result for the above code] Output are:

```
4
4
4
4
4
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
14
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pos = strpos($string, "o", $pos)` sets `$pos` to the position of the found item, and then `$pos++` increments it. This will result in the next match being found *after* the beginning of the current one.

Just using `$pos++` means that the index of start of the search will advance by one each time.